# AngularJS - $scopes in services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, event-listener

So I have a service which I want to allow to listen to events that are fired elsewhere.

I found this question which gives a partial solution: [How do i use $on in a service in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477123/how-do-i-use-on-in-a-service-in-angular)

However what I've got are a single `Listen` service which handles listeners for all my code.
Now I would like to listen to one of the listeners on the `Listen` service from my `user` service.

What I've got so far is this:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('Listen', function ($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        ... 
        a bunch of event listeners
        ... 

        // Event listener
        unique: function(scope, name, callback) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on('unique-' + name, callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },

        activateUnique: function(name){
            $rootScope.$emit('unique-' + name);
        }
    };
    return service;
});
```

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('userService', function (Listen) {
    console.warn('LOADING: user.service.js');
    var session,
        id,
        callDone = false,
        service = {
        ... 
        some service functions
        ...
    };

    service.startSession();

    Listen.unique($scope, id, function() {
        callDone = true;
    });

    return service;
});
```

As you might noticed the `Listen.unique` function needs a `$scope`, which is fine when listening from a `controller` but not when listening from a service, is there a way to get aroung this without making a new `$rootScope.$on('unique-' + name, callback);` in `userService`?

Comment: Would connecting the services in the controller be an option?

Comment: It is bad practice to "connect" 2 modules together. So best way is to "join" the services through a controller, that way you also have the scope available.

Comment: Using a controller is not an option sadly :'-(