# What is the Best way to check internet connection in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Right Now I am Using this code to check the internet connection. And it only checks when it is triggered or called:

```
.factory('Checkinternet', function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup) { 
  return {
      isonline: function() {
         if(window.Connection) {
              if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
                    $ionicPopup.confirm({
                      title: 'No Internet Connection',
                      content: '<span style="color:black">Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.</span>'
                    }).then(function(result) {
                      if(!result) {
                        //ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                      }
                    });
                    return 'off';
              }
          }
      }
  };
})
```

What I want is whenever Internet goes away It should Alert (Without Using `Setinterval` as it is slowing the performance of my app when it runs in background)

Is there any other way Of doing this ??

Comment: you can use http interceptors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to rewrite controller as service, so that it can check network status all over app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058831/trying-to-rewrite-controller-as-service-so-that-it-can-check-network-status-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my other post: [Trying to rewrite controller as service, so that it can check network status all over app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058831/trying-to-rewrite-controller-as-service-so-that-it-can-check-network-status-all/40071984#40071984).

You can check your internet connection anywhere you want by simply add:

```
if(ConnectivityMonitor.isOnline()){

   //do something

}else{

  //do something else 
  alert("No internet connection");
}
```